# BIKA LIMS installation issue on cairoSVG

Tags: python-2.7, open-source, cairo

While running buildout the following issue arising,[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rscCk.png)

I have installed CairoSVG 2.0.0 separately too. Still the same issue arising

Answer (score 0):

CairoSVG 2.0.0 is a Python 3.4+-Library and does not work with Python 2.7.

To solve the issue, open your *buildout.cfg* and add the following line under [versions]:

```
[versions]
...
CairoSVG = 1.0.22
```

Now your buildout should work fine!